# Iterative SQL JOINS using pandas + sqllite3 with a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, for-loop

If I have two tables.  TableA:

| primary key | join_id | distance | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 50 | A |
| 2 | 1 | 100 | B |
| 3 | 1 | 150 | C |
| 4 | 2 | 50 | AA |
| 5 | 2 | 100 | BB |
| 6 | 2 | 150 | CC |

Table B:

| join_id | other value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | X |
| 2 | Y |

And I want to form Table C:

| join_id | other_value | dist_50 | dist_100 | dist_150 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | A | B | C |
| 2 | Y | AA | BB | CC |

What is the simplest strategy for this?  I'm working with pandas dataframes which I convert into a sqlite3 db so i can use pd.read_sql() for queries.

So far, I've tried writing a loop to create a new table for each distance, using a WHERE filter.

```
distances = [50,100,150]
for dist in distances:
    int_tableA_df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM tableA '
                               'WHERE distance == {}'.format(dist), mydb)
    int_tableA_df.to_sql('int_tableA{}'.format(dist), mydb)
```

This does work, but I can't imagine it's the optimal solution, particularly when scaled up (it yields a lot of tables).  Then, I've tried to loop in a similar way to join with each of those previous intermediary tables. (assume tableB_df is previously defined).

```
for dist in distances:
     tableB_df.to_sql('tableB{}'.format(dist), mydb)
     tableB_df = pd.read_sql('SELECT tableB{0}.*, tableA{0}.distance AS dist{0} '
                         'FROM tableB{0} '
                         'LEFT JOIN tableA{0} '
                         'ON tableB{0}.result_id = tableA{0}.result_id'.format(dist), mydb)
```

This gives me a duplicate column level 0 error.  I'm not sure I understand why I would have duplicate columns when I'm creating a new table each loop, just adding one column (with a distinct name) to it.  Any insights to where I'm going wrong would be appreciated!

Also, there has to be a cleaner way to solve this, right?  I know I could just write out a series of left joins for this small example, but that won't scale well with a lot more distances.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Consider conditional aggregation for a single SQL query pull:

```py
sql = '''SELECT a.join_id,
                b.other_value,
                SUM(CASE WHEN a.distance = 50  THEN a.value END) AS dist_50,
                SUM(CASE WHEN a.distance = 100 THEN a.value END) AS dist_100,
                SUM(CASE WHEN a.distance = 150 THEN a.value END) AS dist_150
         FROM tableA a
         LEFT JOIN tableB b AS a.join_id = b.join_id
         GROUP BY a.join_id
      '''

dist_df = pd.read_sql(sql, mydb)
```